# Cannot insert data into SQL Server CE database table in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to insert data into the local database in SQL Server CE, the message box displays that the data insert successfully but there is no data in the database table. I use the following code, please help!

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Code_Genegation_EAE.Properties.Settings.CodeGegerationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into Airport values(@AirportName)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AirportName", textBox1.Text);


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Registered", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            con.Close();
            textBox1.Text = "";

            textBox1.Focus();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly open the connection first?
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Hexie: second line inside the `try` is `con.Open()` .....

Comment: is the table `Airport` contains only one column(`AirportName`)? if not specify column names in insert query

Comment: it would be good to intercept the SQL query on SQL Compact Server... no exception - gives noting to start with

Comment: Can you try writing out the full insert query, i suspect this might be where the issue is? `INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);`

Comment: the table Airport contains only one attribute which is 'AirportName'

Answer (score 0):

Look for a copy of your database file in the bin/ debug folder, it will contain the data

Comment: when i try to retrieve the data from this table it shows nothing

Comment: Your connection string, please - how do you "retrieve the data" ??

Comment: here is my connection string SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Code_Genegation_EAE.Properties.Settings.CodeGegerationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

Comment: That is not your connection string! It usually starts with "Data Source"